# Dynamically assign style to chloropleth map leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, style

I'm trying to create a chloropleth using Leaflet, inspired by the [official Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/), but I've been having some trouble in achieving this, I think due to how my data is structured.

I have a javascript object which has been drawn from a PostGIS database and stored in a dictionary object elsewhere in my project. The following code is used to display the chloropleth when a button is toggled on the website:

```
function getColor(d,range) {
    return  d === null ? '#FFFFFF':
        d > range[6] ? '#800026' :
        d > range[5] ? '#BD0026' :
        d > range[4] ? '#E31A1C' :
        d > range[3] ? '#FC4E2A' :
        d > range[2] ? '#FD8D3C' :
        d > range[1] ? '#FEB24C' :
        d > range[0] ? '#FED976' :
                    '#FFEDA0' ;
    }

function onDataLayerToggled(params) {
    dataLayer = geoDataLayers.find( layer => layer.type == params['dssOverlay'] );
    var range = [500,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000];
    for (i=0;i<dataLayer.layer.options.data.length; i++) {
        dataLayer.layer.setStyle({
            fillColor: getColor(dataLayer.layer.options.data[i]['total'], range),
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
    }
    dssMap.addLayer( dataLayer.layer );
```

The structure of the data section of `dataLayer` (the bit I'd like to assign colours to) is as follows:

`Array(22): [{...}, {...}, {...}, ....]`, where inside each dictionary is the following:

```
aimag_code: 181
camel: 8.11
cattle: 224.995
goat: 1338.223
horse: 236.749
period: 2020
sheep: 1799.761
total: 3607.838
```

When I try to use the above code to assign a colour to the "total" field in each dictionary, it assigns the last RGB code to every value in the array. When I try to implement this in the same way as shown in the leaflet documentation (using the code snippet below), the same result happens.

```
dataLayer.layer.setStyle({
    fillColor: getColor(dataLayer.layer, range),
    ....
}
```

I've been searching around for a solution all day and haven't managed to find something to fix this yet.

Comment: If you look carefully at the cited example, you'll see that style there is a function, depending on feature property. In your code you are setting fixed style in a loop several times, and of course the last setting prevails. You must define style function, where color depends on some feature property and then set style only once.

Comment: Would the best way to do this be to somehow get the "total" data values out from each dictionary object then pass those values into a style function?

Comment: The best solution is to 'attach' these values to features as feature properties at the time of feature creation. Of course on possible solution is also to get value from some global dictionary, but here also you need some feature property that will serve as a key for dictionary search.